# Find successively connected nouns or pronouns in string

Tags: python, spacy, pos-tagger

I want to find stand-alone or successively connected nouns in a text. I put together below code, but it is neither efficient nor pythonic. Does anybody have a more pythonic way of finding these nouns with spaCy?

Below code builds a dict with all tokens and then runs through them to find stand-alone or connected `PROPN` or `NOUN` until the for-loop runs out of range. It returns a list of the collected items.

```
def extract_unnamed_ents(doc):
  """Takes a string and returns a list of all succesively connected nouns or pronouns""" 
  nlp_doc = nlp(doc)
  token_list = []
  for token in nlp_doc:
    token_dict = {}
    token_dict['lemma'] = token.lemma_
    token_dict['pos'] = token.pos_
    token_dict['tag'] = token.tag_
    token_list.append(token_dict)
  ents = []
  k = 0
  for i in range(len(token_list)):
    try:
      if token_list[k]['pos'] == 'PROPN' or token_list[k]['pos'] == 'NOUN':
        ent = token_list[k]['lemma']

        if token_list[k+1]['pos'] == 'PROPN' or token_list[k+1]['pos'] == 'NOUN':
          ent = ent + ' ' + token_list[k+1]['lemma']
          k += 1
          if token_list[k+1]['pos'] == 'PROPN' or token_list[k+1]['pos'] == 'NOUN':
            ent = ent + ' ' + token_list[k+1]['lemma']
            k += 1
            if token_list[k+1]['pos'] == 'PROPN' or token_list[k+1]['pos'] == 'NOUN':
              ent = ent + ' ' + token_list[k+1]['lemma']
              k += 1
              if token_list[k+1]['pos'] == 'PROPN' or token_list[k+1]['pos'] == 'NOUN':
                ent = ent + ' ' + token_list[k+1]['lemma']
                k += 1
        if ent not in ents:
          ents.append(ent)
    except:
      pass
    k += 1
  return ents
```

Test:

```
extract_unnamed_ents('Chancellor Angela Merkel and some of her ministers will discuss at a cabinet '
                     "retreat next week ways to avert driving bans in major cities after Germany's "
                     'top administrative court in February allowed local authorities to bar '
                     'heavily polluting diesel cars.')
```

Out:

```
['Chancellor Angela Merkel',
 'minister',
 'cabinet retreat',
 'week way',
 'ban',
 'city',
 'Germany',
 'court',
 'February',
 'authority',
 'diesel car']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spacy` has a way of doing this but I'm not sure it is giving you exactly what you are after

```
import spacy

text = """Chancellor Angela Merkel and some of her ministers will discuss
at a cabinet retreat next week ways to avert driving bans in
major cities after Germany's top administrative court
in February allowed local authorities to bar heavily
polluting diesel cars.
""".replace('\n', ' ')

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp(text)
print([i.text for i in doc.noun_chunks])
```

gives

```
['Chancellor Angela Merkel', 'her ministers', 'a cabinet retreat', 'ways', 'driving bans', 'major cities', "Germany's top administrative court", 'February', 'local authorities', 'heavily polluting diesel cars']
```

Here, however the `i.lemma_` line doesn't really give you what you want (I think this might be fixed by [this recent PR](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/pull/4219)).

Since it isn't quite what you are after you could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) like so

```
import itertools

out = []
for i, j in itertools.groupby(doc, key=lambda i: i.pos_):
    if i not in ("PROPN", "NOUN"):
        continue
    out.append(' '.join(k.lemma_ for k in j))
print(out)
```

gives

```
['Chancellor Angela Merkel', 'minister', 'cabinet retreat', 'week way', 'ban', 'city', 'Germany', 'court', 'February', 'authority', 'diesel car']
```

This should give you exactly the same output as your function (the output is slightly different here but I believe this is due to different `spacy` versions).

If you are feeling really adventurous you could use a list comprehension

```
out = [' '.join(k.lemma_ for k in j) 
       for i, j in itertools.groupby(doc, key=lambda i: i.pos_) 
       if i in ("PROPN", "NOUN")]
```

*Note I see slightly different results with different `spacy` versions. The output above is from `spacy-2.1.8`*

Comment: Regarding noun_chunks: That might help me even more, if  I can remove the stop works like 'a', 'an', or 'the'. How would you remove those from the noun_chunks spacy elements?